# Digital to analog in an old 35mm film recorder

Tags: analog, video, resolution, crt, ntsc

I'm looking at an old film recorder from 1985, the Polaroid Freeze Frame, the back of the machine pictured here:
[image]

From here: https://www.radiomuseum.org/r/polaroidco_freezeframe_video_recorder.html

I believe the output to 35mm film was 640 x 480, but I'm not sure. I can't find any info online confirming this.

Can a digital signal can be fed into this machine, increasing the resolution?

I know there are converters for everything these days. HDMI to RGB maybe?

Can someone explain the connections available on the back in detail to me, from the time (1985) and if this is possible?

This is the CRT in the machine: http://oddmix.com/tubes/e2787pdw.html

Got this info from the Freeze Frame teardown video on youtube.

Basically I'm wondering what the maximum theoretical resolution is that can be recorded to film using this machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Freeze Frame teardown video you can see that the analog video is digitized using 3 Fujitsu MB840578 'ultra-high speed' 8 bit ADCs, and stored in 7 D41464V 64k x 4 bit RAM chips. This should be capable of storing and displaying a 24 bit image (~16 million colors) at a pixel resolution of 320 x 200 (assuming 8 bits per color channel).

Other resolutions may be possible using less bit bits per pixel, but EGA is only compatible with NTSC in 320 x 200 and NTSC cannot resolve a much higher horizontal resolution, so I doubt that it goes much higher than that.

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to answer. I was rewatching the teardown video of the chips as well. So nothing over 320 x 200, wow that is low.  And going through the RGB analog section would be of no use?

Comment: My question was more or less, can the resolution be modified, with HDMI to RGB or something like that. But if the restrictions are internal on the chips themselves, then yeah, that wouldn't work.

Comment: I've moved this question to: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21762/digital-to-analog-in-an-old-35mm-film-recorder  Do you mind answering what you've answered here there?

Comment: I guess this is a prime example where the 3-vote-close would have worked. Now someone had time to "help".

Comment: You could convert from HDMI to RGB but it wouldn't change the resolution of the device. To do that you would first need to 'reverse-engineer' the circuit and understand how it works. I would enjoy doing that just for fun, but I wouldn't try to hack it into doing something it wasn't designed to do (better, cheaper, easier solutions are available now, so why bother?).

Comment: Gotcha. That's what I needed to know. Cool to learn about this machine none the less! Thanks for the help.